# How to avoid double for loops?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

I want to calculate part of 2 matrices (inner, outer) using data from 2 other matrices. They are all the same size. The code below works but it is too slow on big matrices. I used `np.fromfunction` in another case but was calculating the entire matrix not only a subset.

What's the fastest replacement for the double for loops?

```py
F = np.random.rand(100,100)
S = 10*np.random.rand(100,100) + 1

L,C = F.shape

inner = np.zeros((L,C))
outer = np.zeros((L,C))

for l in range(5, L - 5):
    for c in range(5, C - 5):
        inner[l,c] = np.mean(F[l-5 : l+5 , c-5:c])
        outer[l,c] = np.mean(F[l-5 : l+5 , c+5 : c+5+int(S[l,c])])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `inner` is the result of the convolution of 10x5 averaging filter on `F`. This is quite easy to rewrite as a convolution with `scipy` and it will be as fast as you can get from a CPU. However since you are leaving out 5 rows and columns on the borders of the matrices, you have to truncate the output `inner` and `inner2` matrices accordingly to be able to compare them.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

F = np.random.rand(100,100)
S = 10*np.random.rand(100,100) + 1

L,C = F.shape

inner = np.zeros((L,C))
outer = np.zeros((L,C))

for l in range(5, L - 5):
    for c in range(5, C - 5):
        inner[l, c] = np.mean(F[l-5 : l+5 , c-5:c])
        outer[l, c] = np.mean(F[l-5 : l+5 , c+5 : c+ 5 + int(S[l, c])])

# if inner[l, c] = np.mean(F[l-5 : l+5 , c-5:c+5]),
# then you should use a 10x10 filter
avg_filter = np.ones((10, 5)) / (10*5)
inner2 = convolve2d(F, avg_filter, mode='valid')

# should be very small (1.262e-13 for me)
print((inner2[:89, :89] - inner[5:94, 5:94]).sum())
```

The expression for `outer` is quite strange, because of this `int(S[l, c])` offset that you add to your expression. I don't think you can represent this as a matrix computation.
So to replace your double `for` loop you can use `from itertools import product` which iterates over the cartesian product of two iterables, like this:

```
from itertools import product

for (l, c) in product(range(5, L - 5), range(5, C - 5)):
    outer[l, c] = np.mean(F[l-5 : l+5 , c+5 : c+ 5 + int(S[l, c])])
```

From a signal processing standpoint, I'm not sure what is the `outer` matrix supposed to be. It would be easier to write faster code with the desired effect if you told us what you are trying to do.

Comment: F is a matrix of intensities, S will be a matrix of shadow length that varies by column because the distance to the source increases but also by row because the altitude changes by row. The idea is to get a ratio between the 2 rectangles and add some conditions for the rectangle that represents the object and the one that represents the shadow.

Comment: Ok, I think that you could approach this behaviour by having a 10x15 filter which varies with the current position of the convolution, which is not something scipy can do.
If performance is really an issue, then I would suggest either to write this in Cython, or to look up some more conventional way to produce shadows. In both cases, you'll have to do a little research ;-)